# Keep getting None after my expected result. Trying to get just the 'nth' item of the list printed

Tags: python, list

Question:

Write a function nth_item(data, n) that takes a list data and an integer n as parameters and returns the nth item of the list of data, assuming the first item has an index of n = 0. You may assume that data contains at least n + 1 items.

I can get the right item from the list but always followed by "None". Not sure why "None" keeps appearing or where i'm going wrong.

```
def nth_item(data, n): 
    """Takes a list and an integer and returns the nth item of the        
    list"""
    print(data[n])

item = nth_item([10, 20, 30], 0) 
print(item)
    """should result with:
    10
    but keep getting:
    10
    None
    """
```

Comment: `print`ing something is NOT the same as `return`ing something.

Comment: See where the question says "returns the nth item of the list of data"? In your own words, what does "return" mean in Python? How should you do it?

Comment: Yeah just figured it out, thanks for the help... feeling stupid